# How to refresh particular part of my web page?

Tags: asp.net

I want to refresh only a single part of my page not the whole.
  How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In web forms you can use the update panel

See here for [example](http://www.codegod.de/WebAppCodeGod/UpdatePanel-tutorial-ASP-NET-AJAX-AID281.aspx)

You can also use JQuery although it depends on what you are trying to do and to what complexity.

Comment: For people who stumble upon this. Update panels should now not be used and use ajax instead. See answer by Tarik

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend Update Panel but you can use jQuery `$.load()` method which is pretty slick. Once you start using it, it helps you a lot.

So use Ajax... long story short.

**Edit :**

Maybe this article help as well :

Why Update Panels are Dangerous :

http://encosia.com/2007/07/11/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/

Comment: Can you elaborate why as I have used both and I am interested why the update panel is not recommended?

Comment: Update panel is fine, there is just lot's of FUD and religious flames on it. jQuery is more ubiquitous, and generally a better tool to learn. Update panel is general simpler to get into. jQuery can do much more

Comment: If some thing gives you more convenience, then it takes something more as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "YourPage.aspx/apply",
    dataType: "json",
    data: json.stringify(""),
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
        // window.location.href = "ClubCreation.aspx";
    },
    Error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
});

     [HttpPost]
    public string apply()
    {
        return "Hi";
    }
```

You can use Ajax to solve your problem this code will help you