# refreshing only a specific part / element of a website

Tags: java, android, html, document

What I'm trying is to receive some data off a website which is being refreshed once a second. 
I've been thinking about making use of meta tags, but somehow there aren't any on the website.

I've heen thinking about timers and handlers, but then i would have to refresh the whole site, only to receive the updated data, which is located at the top of the html document. That would cause a lot of traffic.

Is there a way to only refresh a part or even only an element of a page? And if so, how? Currently I'm using jsoup to get data from a document.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to refresh particular part of my web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076849/how-to-refresh-particular-part-of-my-web-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the website is not under your responsibility, and hasn't provided any API or URL used to only get the part of the page you're interested into, then you don't have any other choice: the web page must be reloaded completely. That's how the web works.

Comment: HTTP doesn't have packets. It has a request and a response. The response is transported as one or several TCP packets, but it doesn't change anything: the server will always regenerate the page completely.

Answer (score 2):

Look at ajax. It takes a very simple javascript function call to refresh part of a webpage.
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

If you just want to do a running calculation you can do it with javascript:

```
  document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML= (1+1)
```